# How do you name test files with unit tests in NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, naming

I have a NodeJS backend app using `express` framework.

I want to put my tests into a dedicated folder, say `test` in the root of the project.
And inside that folder I am going to have two sub-folders: `unit` for unit tests and `integration` for endpoint tests.

**My question is what is the common practice around naming the unit-test files when they are not co-located with the source code file that they test?**

I am considering to simply reflect the file path in the test-file name by joining the path with dots, e.g. `controller.products.test.js` for a `products.js` controller code that lives under the `controller` folder.

But is there any common way/convention that people of NodeJS normally follow?

Here is the structure:

```
/
  /models
  /controllers/
    product.js
    category.js
  /middleware/
    auth.js
    validation.js
  /test/
    /unit/
      controllers.product.test.js
      middleware.auth.test.js
    /integration/
      products.test.js
  index.js
  package.json
```

Comment: Curious what you came up with. I wonder if you considered co-locating and/or prefixing. So like, /controllers/product.js would sit next to /controllers/product.test.js, a unit test, and perhaps you put your integration tests where you have them.